# Extended List View is Autoscrolling on Android v9.0

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I am using an extended list view custom control in my app on Xamarin.Forms and it is autoscrolling to the last message when I do a quick swipe up or down (something like when you want to let the list keep scrolling after releasing the swipe). It works fine if I drag the list down and slowly let go of the screen.

None of this is happening on Android 8.0 and the list view is working as it should on 8.0 which is what is really confusing me. Any idea why this is happening and how I can resolve this? Which code should I look at? Putting block points on the "scroll to the first" function I have implemented in the extended list view code do not get triggered from the swipes (the code block does get triggered when it's 
when the "scroll to the first" function is intended though). Is this a bug?

If I can't resolve this issue I might have to revert to regular list view or worse, set the max version of Android to be 8.0 only. Both of which are far from ideal...

EDIT: Turns out it's a OnePlus bug not an Android 9.0 bug. When I downgrade the version to 8.0, it still has the scrolling bug on my Android 9.0

Comment: It would really help, if you could post the XAML of your View/Page and maybe the code behind.

Comment: I'm not sure how my code will help people figure out how to pinpoint the problem that's exclusively happening on a model of a phone... The code is working fine in all other phone models.

Comment: @Asad,According to your description, this issue just encounter in Android 8.0, other Android version works fine? Or you just have this issue on specific phone model? You can provide one sample at github, I will download your sample to test at my side.

Comment: Please read my edit. I included that it's not a version bug but a specific model bug. I have yet to test it on iOS so it could be happening there too. Please give me some time to strip out the code needed for the list view and to upload it on Github. Will get back to this soon. Thank you so much for offering to help.

Comment: @Asad, Anything update about this issue?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT haven't had the time yet. This is a low priority bug in my system right now. Will get around to it soon.

Comment: @Asad, If you have solution, please share your solution here, thanks.